# java CountDownLatch in a thread and race condition

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that must read the stdin and the stdout from a console application. This thread must to read continually until the end of the java program (the java program starts the console application and read and write with him).
Now I have this question: the tread, when reads from console application, if reads a determined thing must to set a flag variable that runs an exception. I solved putting a latch CountDown. But when the thread doesn't read this thing, the barrier `latch.await()` locks the continuos of the java program and I don't know how to resolve this trouble.
This is the part of code:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("testpad -i -c"+can+" -n"+pad+" "+pathFile);
            final InputStream inStream = p.getInputStream();

            Thread uiThread = new Thread("UIHandler") {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
                  Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader);
                  String prec=null;

                  while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    prec=scan.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(prec);

                    if(err.equals(prec)){
                        flag[0] = 1;
                        latch.countDown();
                    }

                  }

               }
            };
            uiThread.start();               
            latch.await();

            if(flag[0]!=1){
                this.dispose();
                new menu().setVisible(true);
            }
            else{
                Exception e = new Exception("Error!");
                Component f = null;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, err, e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                this.dispose();
                new inizio().setVisible(true);
            }
```

In the `if` in the thread there is the part that sets the flag variable. But if the thread doesn't enter there, the java program blocks for the barriel `latch.await()`. Is there a method to do this thing and never blocks the program? Thanks at all.

Comment: Try to use `CyclicBarrier` instead of `CountDownLatch`. Then you should start the required number of threads. you will get control at a barrier point when all thread complete its execution. Also check `ExecutorService`

Comment: but, in your opinion, I must to have more of one thread ? I don't understand

Comment: You already have multiple threads. uiThread is another thread than the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but one thread never finish because he is listening ever for the input (uiThread), then the CyclicBarrier doesn't wait forever?

Comment: In that case, I have not understood your question completely. Is this correct. You are reading some data  continously. When ever you read some data you wanna do some task (Task may be handled by other thread). The read is still going on right ?

Comment: yes, it is my trouble but I'm new in java and I not know how to do it

Comment: Can you see this. A simple implementation of what i discussed. https://gist.github.com/ViswanathL/ca9196af89e7c5801c2f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`latch.await()` will block until the latch finishes so you should move that line to the end.

Comment: but by doing so, the main thread always check the condition "if" before the thread has read all output.